# Avoiding escaped values in closures

Tags: c#, closures, lazy-evaluation, linq-expressions

Assume I have the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    //"i" is captured in the closure passed to LazyCreate
    MyApi.AddLazyCreate(() => new foo(/*other params*/ i)); 
}
```

This will result in an unintentional behavior since "i" will be 10 for all the added closures.

Is there a safe way to avoid this? 
e.g. if I design my api using an `Expression<func<foo>>`
if each "AddLazyCreate" examines the expression passed and store copies of those values, then it should be possible to acheive the intended behavior, right?
that is, I have to compile each argument from the expression and get the temporal value of the argument and recreate the new expression using the evaluated args.
(the expression will always be a "new" expression)

Or am I missing something fundamental here?
Are thre edgecases where I will still get weird behaviors?

Comment: According to Eric this will be 'fixed' in C# 5 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx

Comment: @Maarten Only in foreach loops. For loops still capture the last result.

Comment: @TylerD87 I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    int number = i;
    MyApi.AddLazyCreate(() => new foo(/*other params*/ number)); 
}
```

This will cause it to capture a different number on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: omg how could I have missed that!?, is that behavior changed from earlier versions of .NET??, I'm pretty sure the only way to do this was to create the closure in it's own function, closing over function args

Comment: @RogerAlsing Nope, this worked since lambdas were introduced.